# How to code for user controlled movement of patches in the interface

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a traffic simulation model where the user can move patches (that would act as nodes or junctions). Firstly is this possible , and if so would it be possible to see a code example? Secondly once this is done , will it be possible for the user to draw necessary links between nodes, upon which turtles can travel? 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you describe is very possible by combining a couple ideas. Check out two models in the the Code Examples folder of the Models Library: "Link-Walking Turtles" and "Mouse Drag One".